# CKAN facets for 'author' field gives tokenized values

Tags: search, solr, ckan

I have added a facet to my dataset search by implementing `dataset_facets()`, following this documentation:

http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IFacets

More specifically, I have added a facet for the `author` field, using this code:

```py
def dataset_facets(self, facets_dict, package_type):
    if package_type == 'dataset':
        facets_dict['author'] = toolkit._(u'Author')
    return facets_dict
```

Unexpectedly, the facet values that show up in the facet list are the tokenized and lower-cased author names, rather than the full names. I.e., if I have these author names:

```
[ 'Amt für Statistik', 'Senatsverwaltung für Kultur', 'VBB' ]
```

Then I get the following facet values:

```
[ 'amt', 'fur', 'kultur', 'statistik', 'senatsverwaltung', 'vbb' ]
```

It seems the reason for this is the Solr schema entry for the `author` field, which says `type="textgen"`. Not knowing much about Solr, I have experimented with this and changed it to `type="string"`, and now it works, i.e., I get the full author names as facet values.

My question(s):

- Why was `textgen` chosen for the `author` field?
- Is choosing `string` instead likely to break something else in CKAN? So far, I didn't notice any problems.
- Is there a better way to have facets based on `textgen`-typed fields (e.g., copying the field to a new field with type `string`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that after changing it to a string field, searching against that same field will require an exact hit. Since no processing takes place, the string isn't being broken into separate pieces or lowercased, etc., so to get a match against the field the complete search string has to be used, `Amt für Statistik`. Just `statistik` will no longer give a hit.

I'm not familiar with CKAN, so unless it's using the field for searching, it should work just fine. If, however, it's being used for searching as well, your next suggestion would be the preferred way to solve it.

Copying the field into a separate `string` field to be used for faceting is the preferred way to solve issues like this - one field for searching, one field for faceting. Use different definitions to get different behavior and pick the field most appropriate for what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, here is what I did based on [MatsLindh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49451398/9539770):

Define an additional author field in `schema.xml`:

```
<!-- Copy the author field into authorString, and treat as a string
     (rather than textgen). This allows to use author as a facet for search. -->
<field name="author_string" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

Copy `author` field into `author_string`:

```
<copyField source="author" dest="author_string"/>
```

Use the new field to generate the facet in CKAN:

```
def dataset_facets(self, facets_dict, package_type):
    if package_type == 'dataset':
        facets_dict['author_string'] = toolkit._(u'Author')
    return facets_dict
```

Now I can have a facet with complete strings but still search on partial strings.